# inserting the same value continuously in vba-excel

Tags: vba, excel

I'm newbie in vba.. i don't know how to loop the same value from the existing field of sheet. I had search on in but I didn't find what i'm searching for.

This is my case .For example. i have a field like this :

```
year     value
2012     100
2013     300
2014     400
```

i have new data 2015 that must be insert for 5 times and the result must be like this

```
year     value
2012     100
2013     300
2014     400
2015     900
2015     900
2015     900
2015     900
2015     900
```

I did my code like this :

```
Private Sub AddPostClick_Click()
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Worksheets("DATA")

    lRow = ws.Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlRows, _
        SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Row + 1

With ws

        If CheckBox1.Value = False Then
                For lRow = 1 To 5
                    .Cells(lRow + 1, 1).Value = tYear.Value
                    .Cells(lRow + 1, 2).Value = txtValue.Value
                Next lRow
        End If

End With
End Sub
```

my code will be replace the previous rows, not insert it continuously from the last existing row. This is my problem.

Comment: This is the problem `For lRow = 1 to 5`. You need to declare a new variable (e.g. `i`) and use that as the loop. Example: `For i = 1 to 5` and then `.Cells(lRow + i, 1).Value` etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're overwriting `lrow`. Declare a new `long`. Call `i` and use it as counter.

```
        Dim i as long
        For i = Lrow + 1 To lrow + 1 + 5 
                    .Cells(i, 1).Value = tYear.Value
                    .Cells(i, 2).Value = txtValue.Value
                Next lRow
```

Comment: I agree this answer works. I think it is more readable to have the loop counter as `For i = 1 to 5` and then `.Cells(lRow + i, 1)` to find the cell. Just my opinion.